# override socketio listener (settings several similar listener)

Tags: javascript, socket.io

what is happening if I write

```
socket.on('db' , function() {
    //Execute set of actions 1
});

socket.on('db' , function() {
    //Execute set of actions 2
});
```

What set of action will be executed ? is one overriding the other?

Answer (score 1):

`socket` is an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), so both fire.

Comment: seems obvious indeed ^^ Is there a way to override it ?

Comment: [yep](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname). If you want one of these to only fire once, there is also `socket.once`. You can wire up the `on` callback inside the callback to that one.